# alternative insuluation for stainless steel dishwasher?

Tags: insulation, dishwasher

I just bought a new kitchenaid stainless steel dishwasher. The bad thing is it has stinky odor from the black insulation. Most likely lots of stainless steel dishwashers are using such kind of stinky material. I know it and I hate it because my German car has similar odor which make me sick. Instead of return the dishwasher, I prefer to replace the insulation with something different.

I am glad to see that this insulation layer is easy to remove (see 2nd picture).

So I am looking for alternative healthy replacement for the insulation solution? Will there be any issue if no insulation? Does insulation for dishwasher need fire resistant?

Appreciate if any recommendation on any kind of alternative insulation.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close as seeking a product recommendation. A more targeted question, such as what to look for in insulation, or if it is needed at all, would be more appropriate.

Comment: I will mark it closed. Project failed :( . I found that this asphalt insulation even exists on the bottom so I am not able to scrape it off. Going to dump it now....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a perfect insulation which is suitable for dishwasher: [UltraTouch Radiant Barrier](http://www.homedepot.com/p/UltraTouch-48-in-x-24-ft-Radiant-Barrier-30000-11424/100661257)

[image]

Comment: Product has been discontinued (just FYI for those in 2021 and beyond)

Answer (score 1):

[This type of "blanket"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0053Y2A1A) is commonly used for sound insulation in dishwashers.  It could work for you if the tolerances allow it.  The insulation is there solely to insulate for temperature and sound.

Comment: The sound aspect is much more significant than the insulation aspect, having felt this material with the dishwasher running.

Answer (score 0):

Consumer Reports basically rates dishwashers on their noise level, because they're *all* capable of cleaning dishes. Everyone one of them I've ever seen has a heat coil in it, so if your willing to accept a slight loss in efficiency, and up the noise level -possibly quite a bit- then go ahead and tear it off.

However, I'd wait at least a week to see if the off-gassing lessens to an acceptable level (putting it in the sun for a few days would speed up the process). PJ's 'blanket' is exactly what you'll <s>need</s> want if you do though.

Answer (score 0):

We have exactly the same dishwasher, I think. I never noticed any off-gassing at all on the insulation. It comes with the fleece blanket as well as the matting (which is possibly there to increase mass, and decrease noise.